# Magento 2:Sending Emails Programatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, email-templates, send-mail

I want to send emails from my custom module programatically. Email sending is working fine.

Here is my controller file:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'company_module/general/lease_from_mail';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'company_module/general/template';



    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    protected $remoteAddress;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteAddress,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($post);exit;
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($post);             
        /*Email Sending Start*/

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $senderInfo = [
            'name' =>  $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeScope),
            'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeScope)
        ];  
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($senderInfo)
            ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
            ->getTransport();


            $transport->sendMessage();


          /*Email Sending End*/

    }
}
```

This is my email template.

```
<!--@subject Lease Form  @-->
<!--@vars {
"var this.getUrl($store, 'admin')":"Warehouse Account URL",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"var customer.name":"Customer Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->

<!-- here $myvar1 , $myvar2, $myvar3, $myvar4, $myvar5, $myvar6 are variables in which we
                                     asssign values when we use this template for send mail-->

<!-- you can Modify content of template according to your requirement-->
<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">Hi,</p>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
          <p>{{trans "Test test "}}</p> 
          <p><strong>Equipment Requested:- </strong> {{$data.email()}} </p>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!--footer of template-->
```

I have passed the `$postObject` as data object. I want to get each variable in that object in the template. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try with just `{{var data.email}}` instead of `{{$data.email()}}`

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 0):

If the content of `$postObject` is an associative array, for example something like this:

```
$postObject= [
    'email' => 'test@test.com'
];
```

Then you can do the following in your template:

```
{{var email}}
```

If your `$postObject` is an instance of `Magento\Framework\DataObject` then you'll have to convert it to an array first by calling:

```
$postObject = $postObject->toArray();
```

Comment: Can you please look into my edited question.

Comment: @V.P see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to write below line in your email html,

```
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
```

Comment: you can close this question after accept as answer.